# Edit/Update method, collection_select, called from nested form, get an ID if I am not passing it in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Inside a nested form I am using relation table (has_many through:) in collection_select for edit/update methods.

When I use raise params.inspect (to check my params)- inside update method, the params for language_users_attributes contains:

```
"language_users_attributes"=> {"0"=>{"language_id"=>"5", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"11"}, "1595001921026"=>{"language_id"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1595001921984"=>{"language_id"=>"4", "_destroy"=>"false"}}
```

**Where does the id attribute come from?** It is an ID from language_users table, but I did not pass it in, why is it there?

View looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= f.collection_select :language_id, Language.all, :id, :language, {}, {} %></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', '#', class: 'remove_record' %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

DB Schema:

```
  create_table "language_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "language_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "languages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "language"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_users_on_company_id"
  end
```

Controller:

```
  def edit
    @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:id])
    @teacher.languages.build unless @teacher.languages.present?
  end

  def update
    @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:id])
    if @teacher.update(teacher_edit_params)
      redirect_to teachers_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  Private
      def teacher_edit_params
        params.require(:teacher).permit(:first_name, language_users_attributes: [:id, :language_id, :_destroy])
      end
  end
```

Comment: For an existing language_user record, that is its id, supplied because the nested form is doing its thing which is filling the child records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign a relation with the collection helpers you just need to use the `_ids` setter and getter [created by the `has_many`/`has_and_belongs_to_many` methods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations).

You don't need [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations) or [fields_for](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiThMq6gNXqAhVEtIsKHUQuAzMQ0gIoATABegQIBRAJ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.rubyonrails.org%2Fv5.2.2%2Fclasses%2FActionView%2FHelpers%2FFormHelper.html%23method-i-fields_for&usg=AOvVaw1J-JTOYU_c__V5wMsT3jhV).

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :language_ids, Language.all, :id, :language %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(..., language_ids: [])
end
```

This setter takes an array as input and will automatically create/delete records in the join table.

Nested attributes only need to be used if you are assigning additional attributes to the join table like for example if the user was selecting a language as well as their level of proficiency. This should not be confused with a single select or a series of checkboxes.

In that case the `id` attribute comes in as its what toggles `accepts_nested_attributes` between updating existing records or creating new records.